# html form check value with text

Tags: html

i have simple question, let's say i have input like this:

```
<input name="somename" type="checkbox" value="1" />
```

Is it possible to change `value="1"` to `value="some text"` or `value="some_name"`.
What i mean is it possible to use symbols instead of numbers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course you can. You can define the value you want.

Look at this sample: http://jsfiddle.net/UB9tV/

Answer (score 1):

I was curious so I gave it a try. Check it out:

```
<h1> check this thing</h1>
<input id="somename" type="checkbox" value="test" />

<a href='javascript:showCheckValue()'>Check</a>

<script>
    function showCheckValue()
    {
        var sn = document.getElementById('somename');
        alert(sn.value);
    }
</script>
```